# Wine Installation on Ubuntu 20.04 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 doesn't work

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg

i have some issues installing Wine, because Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't recongnize i386 Architecture when I run the command to add it on the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

returns

```
pkg-config-dpkghook: aviso: Architecture t386 not defined in architecture tables, ignored
pkg-config-dpkghook: aviso: Architecture 1386 not defined in architecture tables, ignored
```

Need some advice to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mistype the name? `1386 ` is not the same as `i386` (nor `t386` for that matter)

Comment: I've just needed to do this, and it works for me - Ubuntu 20.04, June 2020.

Comment: I'm sure i didn't mistype the name. I typed i386. What else could it be?

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Strange thing is, I don't get any error message. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` exits without any message, but doesn't add the architecture: `sudo dpkg --print-architecture` only shows amd64. Puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I give my comments in case that someone encounter this confusing message in the future like me.
A simple answer is that `l386`  and `t386` were accidently added before `i386` is added. You can refer to [another question in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280553/what-is-this-amdg4).
Here is the details.

Following two *incorrect* commands were executed accidently

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture l386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture t386
```

Then this **correct** command is executed, `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. You will see the warnings.

```
pkg-config-dpkghook: aviso: Architecture t386 not defined in architecture tables, ignored
pkg-config-dpkghook: aviso: Architecture l386 not defined in architecture tables, ignored
```

Actually, i386 has been added successfully. If  this command is executed, `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. The output will be like this:

```
t386
l386
i386
```

You can eliminate these confusing message by the following command.

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture t386
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture l386
```

Afterwards, execute the command again `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. Only `i386` will be shown.

Following is just my thoughs on the messages.
The user is confused because the warning is not caused by this command. More details should be added in the message so that the users can know why the warning pops up.