# What is this amdg4?

Tags: wine, architecture

I try get the i386 dependencies for wine but i get this error:

```
pkg-config-dpkghook: warning: Architecture amdg4 not defined in architecture tables, ignored
```

and this what architecture i have:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
amdg4
```

what can i do?

Comment: I think you accidentally fat-fingered the amd64 syntax when adding an arch into your system.  amdg4 is not a valid arch and should be removed from the config with steeldriver's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, `amdg4` is not a valid architecture. You can remove it with

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture amdg4
```